# Android Camera2 API separate callback for every photo taken

Tags: android, api, camera, android-camera

I want to instantiate MyCamera2Manager class from another class and initialize it.

```
public void MyCamera2Manager (){
    initStuff(); //such as openCamera, createCaptureSession, etc.
}
```

After, i want to be able to call a class method **takePhoto** on that instance, pass in a callback, and receive a bitmap

```
public void takePhoto(TaskCallback<Bitmap> bitmapListener){ 
    //where can I send this bitmapListener?

    CaptureRequest.Builder requestBuilder = ...
    requestBuilder.addTarget(mImageReader.getSurface());
    CameraRequest request = requestBuilder.build();

    mCaptureSession.capture(request, ...)
}
```

I don't know how to do this because I only have **1** ImageReader with **1** OnImageAvailableListener with which to listen for photos. Ideally I would like to pass all my **bitmapListener**s to separate ImageReaders, get the image from them and pass it back to my **bitmapListener**.

I tried to construct an ImageReader every time I called **takePhoto()**  (not like above), and therefore create a new **ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener** each time and pass to it my initial **bitmapListener** but this doesn't work because I need to instantiate a valid ImageReader beforehand so I can construct a **CaptureSession**.

or

Should I create a CaptureSession every time I take a picture? That doesn't seem right. I can't do this either because every new **CameraDevice.createCaptureSession()** destroys the previous one.

I know what I wrote is a bit of a mess but I can't explain it in any other way. I hope someone can decipher.

Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, you won't be able to do this without either using 1 ImageReader to get all the camera outputs, or creating a new CameraCaptureSession with new registered ImageReaders each time (HIGHLY discouraged). Why do you need one ImageReader per bitmapListener, instead of just reusing a single one?

Comment: I basically have a viewpager with let's say 30 pages. Most of the pages are some pictures but inbetween them (random) are some image placeholders. When the viewpager reaches a placeholder it triggers the takePhoto() method I was talking about in my question, it passes the method a listener and when the bitmap comes back, it sets the photo on that exact location in the viewpager. It's important that I pass a different listener for each takePhoto() call because I need to know to what ImageView i need to set each photo that comes back from camera.

Comment: basically the problem is, I have nowhere to pass those different listeners inside the camera work flow. The CameraCaptureSession + the ImageReader + the ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener (where I get the photo data) are all constructed beforehand.  When I call takePhoto(), I just need to call CameraCaptureSession.capture(..). There's nowhere to pass any listeners. I could pass only 1 when I construct the class, but that's not enough.